# Create std::vector in-place from raw data

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, memory-management

Given a raw array of elements, how to create a `std::vector` that takes ownership of the raw array without reallocate & copy?

For example having the raw array:

`int* elems = new int[33]`

how to create a `std::vector` of size `33` pointing to `elems`?

I am sure that theoretically this is possible, as usually `std::vector` is implemented as a structure containing three pointers, one pointing to the beginning of the allocated memory, one to the end of the valid elements, and one to the end of the allocated memory. But is there a standard way of initializing the `std::vector` structure with the raw array?

Comment: You can’t. Don’t use new for your „raw data“, use the vector.

Comment: You can store pointer to array in `unique_ptr<int[]>` and access array content through `array_view<int>` if you need usual methods such as `begin` or `front`.

Comment: Do the opposite: have the `vector` manage the memory, and create a pointer to it `std::vector<int> v; int* elems = v.data();`

Comment: unless I'm missing something, from c++11, in theory one could write an allocator for that. That said, there's hardly a good reason to do so .

Comment: pls stop judging/finding reasons for doing this, just answer the question if you can; if you really need reasons how about not being able to change an external library that returns raw pointers, which I need to integrate in a modern framework using std?

Comment: It's usually worth adding information like that to the question, to make it clear you cannot change raw array. Otherwise people will just try to educate you. You can [edit] your question to include information like this.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a "view" rather than a container. Containers own their elements and their main purpose is to encapsulate the raw memory they manage. If you need to manage the memory yourself then you dont need a container. Take a look at `string_view` that would be your solution if you had a `string`. Perhaps [boost ranges](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/range/doc/html/range/concepts/overview.html) is something that you could apply. From the docs (emphasize mine):

> The motivation for the Range concept is that there are many useful
>   Container-like types that do not meet the full requirements of
>   Container, and many algorithms that can be written with this reduced
>   set of requirements. In particular, a Range does not necessarily
>
> - **own the elements that can be accessed through it**,
> - have copy semantics,

PS: Actually `std::array_view` was considered for C++17, but unfortunately it didnt make it into the standard.

Comment: `std::array_view` didn't make it into C++17.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why this is not directly possible is that the standard library uses allocators to reserve memory for the containers.

Therefore if you have an `std::vector` which uses a certain type of allocator and give it some pointer you have created, you effectively break the allocator idiom. If your implementation of the standard library for example uses `malloc` and `free` instead of `new` and `delete`, your program will fail.

For this to become a *standard way*, the standard library would need to provide a constructor that accepts a `T*` which additionally must have been returned by the same allocator the vector uses later. So the signature of the constructor you need would be something like `std::vector::vector(T* data, size_type used_elements, size_type capacity, const Allocator& alloc)`. Notice that the allocator argument is necessary as the `T*` must (theoretically) have been returned by the exact same allocator that is used in the vector.

---

You can achieve <strike>some of the functionality</strike> this by creating your own allocator according to [this concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator), but to have your `33` elements to not be reconstructed you will also have to provide a `allocator::construct(..)` function which is a no-op until the `34th` element (exclusive). Additionally you will have to initially resize your vector to `33` elements to force the vector to have the correct size.

That being said this nevertheless is a bad idea because for the conditional construct and allocate functions you will probably have more overhead opposed to copying your elements once.

Comment: The declaration of `std::vector` is
```template<
    class T,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<T>
> class vector;
```
so the created vector can be accompanied by the right allocator, including for `malloc` and `free`

Comment: @cDc Yes it is, but unfortunately I don't know what you want to tell me with this..

Comment: @nyronium I think you *can* write a legit allocator to do what the OP wants; said allocator would check that the T* and size it's initialized with match the arena memory and turn allocation and construction as almost no-ops ( of course, the allocator would still copy on grow ) ...

Comment: @cDC of course, I'm not saying it would be a good idea though; there are much better ways for interfacing with c-like-apis ...

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes Yes you are right, but as for the `34th` element `construct` is not a no-op, this will probably have more overhead than just copying the array once. So as you said this is probably a bad idea... :)

Answer (score 1):

In accordance to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), there is no constructor that accepts pointer to data. So, you can't pass the ownership over raw array to vector.

You can only create a vector and place data into it.

Comment: I know according to the cited source there is no way to do this, but don't you find that this is both possible and useful and that should be possible to do it?

Comment: @cDc How could the vector safely take ownership of a pointer? There's no way to restrict this to dynamically allocated pointers.

Comment: Not sure what you mean; by taking ownership I mean the `elems` variable will not be used anymore after `std::vector` creation, and all management of the array will be done through `std::vector` methods, including adding/removing elements.

Comment: @cDc: It is *not* useful for `std::vector` because it breaks fundamental assumptions about its ownership semantics. It would be useful as a different kind of tool, something like `std::string_view`. However, `std::array_view` did not make it into C++17, AFAIK because things got too complicated with multi-dimensional arrays(?).

Answer (score 0):

If the type of the object you are working on is movable, you can do this:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> ConvertArrayToVector(T* data, size_t size)
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> result(size);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<size; ++i)
        result[i] = std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<T>(data[i]));

    return result;
}
```

The resulting vector owns the array now, in a sense that it stores pointers to its elements and makes sure the objects are deleted when the vector is destroyed, but the original array gets invalidated in the process.

Answer (score -1):

> Given a raw array of elements, how to create a `std::vector` that
>   takes ownership of the raw array without reallocate & copy?

There is no way.

> how to create a `std::vector` of size 33 pointing to elems?

Impossible.

> I am sure that theoretically this is possible,

No, it isn't.

> But is there a standard way of initializing the `std::vector` structure with the raw array?

No.

---

That being said, chances are that you may be able to hack together a solution with a custom allocator. However, in addition to the fact that writing custom allocators is a rarely-used error-prone technique, you shouldn't overestimate the usability of such a solution.

`std::vector<int>` and `std::vector<int, MyAllocator>` are **two different classes**. If your goal is to interface with code that expects `std::vector<int>`, then `std::vector<int, MyAllocator>` cannot be used; and if you intend to create and use `std::vector<int, MyAllocator>` in your code, then honestly you'd be better off just implementing your own non-owning container class, i.e. something like a custom `VectorView<T>`.